# Run javascript after CSS is dynamically load and rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to load css files dynamically, and run a js script after the css is *rendered* on the document. I want to use an element's new width and height which is set by the loaded css.. So it's important to run the js after render. Is it possible? I'm using jQuery.

Comment: Put your Javascript code after the CSS?

Comment: I want to load dinamically the CSS, with JS, so its not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [SidJS](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/sidjs-load-javascript-and-stylesheets-on-demand):

> SidJS is a lightweight JavaScript library that allows one to include JavaScript scripts and CSS stylesheets on demand. It supports callbacks tied to the loading process to guarantee that the resources you're loading are available when you need them.

In other words, you request a style sheet and provide a callback function. The callback function is executed when the style sheet has been loaded. Example:

```
Sid.css("my-sheet.css", function() {
    // Perform your width/height logic here.
});
```

I'm not completely sure if the document will have had time to redraw by the time the callback is executed, but you should try it out. Worst case scenario, you simply delay your logic by 100ms or so using `setTimeout`.

Comment: It is probably best to use this third party javascript library to accomplish the goal - the reason is because attaching a .css file dynamically has a nasty problem in old IE - you cannot listen for any load event that is called AFTER the CSS is available, you have to do non-trivial things to ensure that your callback function is called at the right time.

SidJS will make sure of this - so you don't have to worry. No need for a `setTimeout` Sid is already creating a setTimeout and checking every 100ms if the stylesheet is available in DOM or not - but it only does that if absolutely necessary

Comment: Thank you! My project is for just modern browser with strong HTML5 and CSS3 support otherwise, so using the setTimeout is not a problem. I will try SidJS later. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I understand your need, but I highly recommend to do it only after all alternatives fail.

How many CSS files do you have? how different are they?

It would even be better to set styles in JS rather than using it to load CSS files.

Also, if your need is for JS to know styles loaded from the CSS file, JS will need to know where those files are, right? Isn't it easier to provide those info instead of the file URL?

It's hard to think on alternatives without knowing why exactally you'll only know which file to load after page has loaded. If it's based on some user input, you can just have a CSS file with different styles for a set of classes, and use JS to change element classes, therefore removing a class styles and applying new class styles to it.

Always try to keep all your styles on a unique file, trying to keep it organized and compact, reusing always possible. Then you use JS to change styles, classes and elements as needed.

Comment: I know, its kind of hacking the document, but my goal is make the project more confortable to work with. So, passing the CSS with js sound like the best idea.